# Stack Overflow Chat on Android

Tags: support, chat, android-app

Since I use the Stack Exchange mobile app a lot, and I just reached 20 reputation (which unlocks the chat), I would like to know where the chat is  hiding on the Android mobile app? Because the only chat I can find is the one on the mobile version (and not the app).

Comment: Will there ever be a chat ?

Comment: Refer to [this feature request on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191334/add-chat-rooms-for-android-app) for "official" request.

Comment: I'd stick to the main site, or at the very least use the site through a browser on your mobile. I find the app cumbersome and cluttered at best.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I made [ChatSEy](https://stackapps.com/questions/4659/chatsey-an-android-app-for-se-chat) a while back. It's an app that just loads the normal chat site, but injects some userscripts to (IMO) make it a bit more user friendly.

Comment: I use this - it's quite good:)

Answer (score 6):

There is no chat in the mobile apps at the moment. In [podcast #62](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/02/podcast-62-delete-this-whole-episode/) you can hear a thing or two about that.

As it says on the post

> **Are there any plans to add a chat feature to the mobile application?**
> (Mobile lead Kasra just dropped dead.) We may add chat to the mobile app yet, but it’s not in our 2015 plan.

And as [Kasra Rahjerdi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/472021/kasra-rahjerdi) (lead of the Mobile team) said - in the live-chat for said podcast - [in a response](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19638247#19638247) to the exact question you're asking:

> [...] not in the immediate future. it'd require an API for chat which we don't have yet (and we don't have anyone working full time on chat to make an API for it at the moment)

Comment: Goes 2019 and nearly 2020, no chat 눈_눈 .......... Please, let the beginning of 2020(SOSO) year start with a chat of StackOverflow application, preferably, using material or flat design!

Comment: I believe development on the app halted completely.